# jQuery dataTables: Filter based on string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a table that is being populated by way of a repeater and I have added the relevant dataTable .css and .js to enable the plugin. This works fine and as expected. The issue I am having is how can I now enable a few 'filter buttons' which when clicked apply a string based filter to the table data. I can simulate what I want by using the actual Search Bar that you can enable, but I would prefer to have some anchor tags that serve as clickable buttons/filters to trigger this.

Example Table

```
ID :  Type   
----------
1  :  Car
2  :  Car
3  :  Bike
4  :  Bike
5  :  Car
```

The javascript at the bottom of the page looks like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var filteredData = table
    .columns( [0, 1] )
    .data()
    .flatten()
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value = 'Bike' ? true : false;
    } );
```

I suspect there is an issue with how I am defining my search criteria, and in the example above this is attempting to set a filter on anything within columns 0 or 1 that contain the string 'Bike'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.columns( [0, 1] )
        .search('Bike')
        .draw();
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: Appreciate the response and this has worked well for my purposes.Thank you, Mohsin.